# Two git repos accidentally merged, how to clean up

Tags: git

A client of mine accidentally set a different project as the remote in his `.git/config` file, then pulled, committed and pushed.

This means all of the files from repo "A" (the primary one) now are in repo "B" (the secondary one). Unfortunately, several people have already pulled from "B".

What is the best way to remove all the files, commits and history of "A" from "B"?

Comment: Did they `pull --force` and `push --force`?

Comment: Also, which repository did they push to?

Comment: I don't know if they did a `--force`, but I wouldn't doubt it. They pushed to the second repo. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm presuming your repository looks something like this with A-C being commits in the proper repository and 1-3 being commits in the wrong repository.  D is the merge point between the two as a result of the pull (presumably `pull --force` which you shouldn't do unless you know there's been a rebase).

```
... A - B - C - D [master] [origin/master]
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3
```

All you need to fix this problem is to move master back to C.  Since branches in Git are just labels pointing at commits, they're cheap to move around.  This is what `git reset` does (`git reset --` does something else entirely).

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C
```

`--hard` says to throw out the index and make the working directory match the commit as well.  Now your repository looks like this.

```
... A - B - C [master] - D [origin/master]
                        /
           ... 1 - 2 - 3
```

Now `git push --force` to make the same move in the remote repository.  With nothing else referencing it, the offending commits will eventually be garbage collected.

```
... A - B - C [master] [origin/master]
```

This gets a little bit more complicated if work was done on top of the bad merge.

```
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G [master] [origin/master]
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3
```

You want to do the same thing as before, but hold onto G.  You can do this by writing down the commit ID, or you can tag it to be safe.

```
git tag old-master master
```

Which looks like...

```
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G [master] [origin/master] (old-master)
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3
```

Do a reset as before...

```
... A - B - C [master] - D - E - F - G [origin/master] (old-master)
                        /
         ... 1 -  2 -  3
```

But now you want to hang E, F and G off C.  You can do this with a rebase.  This will take E, F and G as patches and apply them, one by one, onto C.

```
git rebase --onto master D old-master
```

The changes will have new commit IDs, since every commit ID in git depends on their parent's ID (this is what makes pushing and pulling so fast).

```
              E1 - F1 - G1 [master]
             /
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G [origin/master] (old-master)
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3
```

Now you can `push --force` master and delete old-master.

```
... A - B - C - E1 - F1 - G1 [master]
```

Since the repository changed out from under them, everyone who has already pulled from the repository will have to `git pull --force`.  They should probably `git pull --rebase --force`.  A pull is normally a fetch and a merge.  `--rebase` turns this into a fetch and a rebase.  Using rebase will apply the user's unpushed work as patches on top of the new repository.  This prevents the mistaken repository from coming back via a pull/merge.

For example, a user's repository might look like this, with H and I being their own unpushed changes.  I'll also put up the fixed remote repository for comparison.

```
[local]
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G [origin/master] - H - I [master]
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3

[remote]
... A - B - C - E1 - F1 - G1 [master]
```

After you've fixed the remote repository, if they pull Git will refuse to merge since G is not an ancestor of G1, they have to force.  This is simpler to show the fetch and merge/rebase separately.  So `git fetch origin` will result in...

```
[local]
              E1 - F1 - G1 [origin/master]
             /
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I [master]
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3

[remote]
... A - B - C - E1 - F1 - G1 [master]
```

`git merge origin/master`, which is what `git pull --force` would then do, would result in this...

```
               - - - - - - E1 - F1 - G1 [origin/master]
             /                         \
... A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I - J [master]
               /
... 1 -  2 -  3
```

We don't want that, it will resurrect the history from the wrong repository.  `git pull --force --rebase` will instead do a `git rebase origin/master` which will put H and I on top of origin/master.

```
[local]
... A - B - C - E1 - F1 - G1 [origin/master] - H1 - I1 [master]
```

Now they can proceed working as normal (there's no need to immediately push).

Comment: This looks great. I'll give it a try and when it works, you've got my upvote and accept. :)

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall Thanks.  I added instructions for how users who have already pulled and done work can fix this.  I *think* `git pull --force --rebase` will work the way I said, but I would suggest testing it first.  Put a tag on master before doing it so its easy to recover if the rebase doesn't work out.

Comment: Looks like it worked. I had to do a `git reset --hard origin/master` on at least one machine, but other than that seems to be working very well. (The rebase prompted me half a million times about whether or not I wanted to keep each of the files from repo "A").